# Haskell: order of permutation

Tags: list, math, haskell, permutation

i'm new in Haskell. I have to write function that takes list of Integers and returns number of composition needed to recieve identity permutation. Something like that:

```
permutationOrder :: [Int] -> Int
```

I'd be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the list contains the numbers from `0` to `n-1` in some order,

```
toPermutationGraph :: [Int] -> [(Int,Int)]
toPermutationGraph = zip [0 .. ]
```

gives you the graph of the permutation. From the graph, you can easily compute the order by partitioning it into connected components (corresponding to the cycles the permutation is composed of). The order of a cycle is the number of elements in the cycle. Disjoint cycles commute, that makes it easy to compute the order of a product of disjoint cycles.

Comment: Thank you for such quick response. So now I have list of pairs for example: [(1,6),(2,4),(3,1),(4,3),(5,7),(6,2),(7,5)], next I have to merge it [(1,6,2,4,3),(5,7)]. Next I need to count lengths of every cycle and find least common multiple for them, right? What is most difficult for me is how to merge them into disjoint cycles.

Comment: Right. To split it into disjoint cycles, the simplest way would be to use a function `pick :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe (a, [a])` that returns the pair of the first list element satisfying the test and the remainder of the list, like `pick even [1,3,4,5,6] = Just (4,[1,3,5,6])`, to find the cycle from the first element. Iterating gives you the list of all cycles.